# What is a good way to get the filename from a URL in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, url, uri

What is a good way to extract `filename.jpg` from:

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar/filename.jpg?2384973948743'
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar/filename.jpg?2384973948743'

uri = URI.parse(url)

puts File.basename(uri.path)

#=> filename.jpg
```

Answer (score 9):

If you do not expect `query_string` in `url`, you can simply use `File.basename`

```
puts File.basename('http://example.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt')
```

This displays `file.txt`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably to use `URI.parse`

```
url_object = URI.parse([my url])
url_path = url_object.path
filename = url_path.split("/").last
```

Comment: does not account for parameters after basename, still useful answer